# tfs problem :TF31001Team foundation can't retrieve the list of team project from team foundation server

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Q:
When i want to create a new project :

File ---> New ---->Team Project

I get the following error , i googled it but in vain .

## Error:

`TF30224`: Failed to retrieve projects from the report server. Please check that the SQL Server Reporting Services Web and Windows services are running and you have sufficient privileges for creating a project.

when i reinstall sp1 , i get this error.

## Error:

`TF31001`:Team foundation can't retrieve the list of team project from team foundation server.

please any one face the same error help me.
thanks a lot.